# How do I properly index a query that selects multiple fields when using GROUP BY and ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, group-by, sql-order-by

**My Issue**

We have an email engine which sends users emails either in blocks (same email to many users: ie, a bulk newsletter) or singleton cases (one email to one user: ie, a password reset). We have an admin console which displays a log of the emails that have been sent out.

Right now, this table has around 750,000 rows. For every EMAIL that is sent, the following is logged in the table (trimmed down to the main items):

- id
- batch_id
- user_id
- subject
- send_date
- created

If a batch email is sent out, all the emails in that batch will have the same `batch_id`. When an admin is browsing the logs console, we don't want to display all the emails from a batch within the table results - just a unique one. So we did this:

```
SELECT id, batch_id, user_id, subject, send_date, created FROM `emails` 
GROUP BY batch_id
ORDER BY created DESC
limit 10
```

This works, but it is SLOW. This is the result of our EXPLAIN on our query:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | emails_logs | index | NULL          | batch_id | 17      | NULL | 2522 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+----------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Our Goal**

Select unique records for `batch_id`, ordered by the date the records were created in a descending order, quickly.

My question is: How do I index these in the best way, and select the fields in an appropriate manner to take advantage of these indexes?

Thank you!

Comment: Please, refrain from using MySQL's [`GROUP BY` extension](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html).

Comment: Okay, care to elaborate why? Or propose a viable solution?

Comment: I would recommend reading the documentation. You're looking for a  `DISTINCT` result set here.

Comment: I am not selecting `DISTINCT` rows though, just excluding records that have the same `batch_id`

Comment: Then use `HAVING COUNT(batch_id) < 2`.

Comment: If you can stub up a solution or workaround to my question, it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea.  Create an index on `emails(created, batchid)` and another on `emails(batchid)`.  Now do:

```
select e.id, e.batch_id, e.user_id, e.subject, e.send_date, e.created
from (select batchid, created
      from emails
      order by created desc
      limit 10
     ) e10 join
     emails e
     on e.batchid = e10.batchid
group by e.batchid
order by created desc;
```

The idea is to reduce the set you are processing, before doing the aggregation and ordering.

It also sounds like your data would be better if it were more normalized.  One table should have the batch information, including the sender and created date.  The other should have

Comment: This is a good solution, but the limit within the subselect is being invoked on the ungrouped, 'duplicate' records. So if I have a batch email that goes out to say 50 people, when I do the select, its only going to return 1 record, instead of the 10 different ones that I would expect

Comment: @BarryChapman . . . The subquery should use the first index to find the best batches.  The second index should be used for the join.  With the reduced set, the query should run faster.

Comment: I was able to modify this to correctly solve my issue, thanks for your help Gordon!